# Going back and forth from unique id to string back to unique id

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I have a route on my site that displays a badge for a particular user. It works because in the query string that user's id is provided. The database is checked to see if that user has that certification, and then the page is displayed with that user's public info. Currently, the text of the email is that users id. I'd like to user something a little more anonymous. A short unique id.

But, if I do md5 hash or something, then I can't go back to the email so that I can look them up in the database. What is a way I can go back and forth from unique id to email back to unique id? I'm building with node.js, so perhaps something int he crypto library?

Comment: I would generate a hash using node module hat and save it in users table.

Comment: Storing it would reduce the load.

Comment: If ID is integer, try http://hashids.org/node-js/